# In go, how to use mutex to lock and wait with go routines

Tags: go, asynchronous, mutex, goroutine

I have code that is something like this:

```golang
var lock sync.Mutex

func DoSomething() {
  lock.Lock()
  go func() {
    defer lock.Unlock()
    // Code here
  }()
}

func Wait() {
  lock.Lock()
  lock.Unlock()
}
```

I need the `Wait()` because sometimes I have to call `DoSomething()` before a `panic` or `sys.Exit`. So, in those cases, I need it to complete.

It works fine as long as I'm only calling `DoSomething()` once at a time, but of course, if it's called twice, the second one waits before the goroutine is called.

```golang
DoSomething() // returns immediately
DoSomething() // waits until the first one finishes to return
```

And if I put the lock inside the goroutine, then `Wait()` gets called before the goroutine starts.

```golang
func DoSomething() {
  go func() {
    lock.Lock()
    defer lock.Unlock()
    // Code here
  }()
}

DoSomething()
Wait() // this finishes before the goroutine even starts
```

I've tried a few other things in `sync` but haven't found something that works.

I even tried taking the goroutine out of `DoSomething` and calling it like `go DoSomething()`, but I couldn't get that to work either.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the 2nd call waiting for the 1st to finish?

Comment: @Turing85 The reason for using a goroutine here is that, in most cases, it will be non-blocking, unless I explicitly call Wait. So, if the second call is waiting, it's blocking execution after it. Basically, I want it to wait inside the goroutine, not outside it.

Comment: Is it necessary that the 2nd call to `doSomething()` is executed? Or can it be skipped?

Comment: It is necessary, but, so far, it never actually happens in the code as close to that as I've used in the example. The code is logging important information. The calls have to happen, they can't happen simultaneously, and they ideally have to happen in order. But only rarely do two calls to the function happen so close to each other. I may actually be willing to live with this, if I can't find a better solution.

Comment: I am almost certain that something should be possible with channels.

Comment: I thought of channels, but I can't quite wrap my head around how to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [sync.WaitGroup](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#WaitGroup):

```
package main

import "sync"

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func DoSomething() {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        // Code here
    }()
}

func Wait() {
    wg.Wait()
}
```

WaitGroup.Wait waits until Done has been called as many times as the sum of all values passed to Add. In other words: call Add with the number of goroutines you are about to start, and each goroutine calls Done when it's done. Wait blocks until all goroutines have called Done.

Comment: This solution does not guarantee that multiple calls to `DoSomething()` are not executed simultaneously, does it?

Comment: @Turing85, correct. That would have to be arranged by the callers of DoSomething. A function has no control over how it is called.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, but used a combination of a mutex and a waitgroup. The mutex locks at the beginning of the goroutine.

So, the top of the goroutine is `lock.Lock(); defer lock.Unlock(); defer wg.Done()`

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am still learning go. I am not 100% sure that this is the idiomatic way to go (pun intended).

---

The idea for this solution is: instead of calling a method directly, we:

- start a go routine from the get-go, which waits on some signal on a channel
- when we want to do something, we write to the channel
- to possibly synchronize with the execution, we can pass another channel on the channel - the back communication channel

Putting it all together, we get something like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

// This is the channel used by doSomething() to be notified when it should run
var doSomethingChannel = make(chan chan<- interface{})

// This is the channel we expose as interface to the outside so we can trigger "doSomething" to... do something
func DoSomethingChannel() chan<- chan<- interface{} {
    return doSomethingChannel
}

func doSomething() {
    for {
        back := <-doSomethingChannel
        // code goes here
        fmt.Println("[GOROUTINE] Executing")
        time.Sleep(200 * time.Millisecond)
        fmt.Println("[GOROUTINE] Done")
        if back != nil {
            back <- struct{}{}
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    go doSomething()
    for i := 0; i < 11; i += 1 {
        // when i is even, define a back-channel and wait
        var back chan interface{} = nil
        if i%2 == 0 {
            back = make(chan interface{})
            fmt.Printf("[CALLER] Waiting for execution %d\n", i)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("[CALLER] Calling for execution %d, will not wait\n", i)
        }

        // send the back-channel to the DoSomethingChannel, this will trigger doSomething()
        DoSomethingChannel() <- back

        // If back channel is set, wait for response
        if back != nil {
        // read from the back channel if possible. Otherwise, do something else (simulated by a sleep here)
        LOOP:
            for {
                select {
                case <-back:
                    fmt.Printf("[CALLER] execution %d has been done\n", i)
                    break LOOP
                default:
                    fmt.Printf("[CALLER] Still waiting for execution %d...\n", i)
                    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[<kbd>`go.dev` demo</kbd>](https://go.dev/play/p/UbtXEas62tj)